# No sound out of both sides of Beats solo3 wireless when on Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I have a pair of beats solo3 wireless headphones that used to work.

1. They still work when wired.
2. When connected to my phone over bluetooth, I can see the iPhone volume indicators change on the iphone when I press the volume buttons on the headphones. So it's definitely connected to bluetooth.
3. I tried resetting by holding power button and volume down button for 10 seconds. It didn't help.
4. Tried getting it to work with Apple Watch and iMac but it doesn't work with them.
5. I no longer get chime that I used to hear when the headphones are first turned on.
6. After fiddling with it some more, I was able to briefly get some sound  out of one side at a very low volume. Then I got sound out of the other for about 5 seconds and then it cut out completely. So they are still not working but there seems to be a glimmer of hope.
7. After sticking the wired cable into the jack on the left can about halfway in while they were connected to bluetooth, I was able to restore sound do the right can. Still no sound out of left can. Very weird.

Any other ideas or are these things toast?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

So after 7) above, I poked the wired cable into the jack again (the cable was totally disconnected at the other end this time). The headphones turned themselves off. After I turned them on, they miraculously started working.